# Create parent ids for rows in a dataframe in python based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a big data frame with records of individuals. I'm trying to create a parent ID for people that match on specific columns to know which records in fact refer to the same person.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                   'forename':['matt','mark','matthew','chris','rob','robert','john','mat'],
                   'surname': ['smith','smith','smith','jones','quiton','quiton','rogers','smith'],
                   'phone': ['77881','77882','77881','66777','12299','93923','77881','37882'],
                   'email': ['email1@email.com','email2@email.com','email3@email.com','email4@email.com','email5@email.com','email5@email.com','email7@email.com','email1@email.com'],
                   'group': ['greggs','kikland','greggs group','dmrc','curve','tools','baron','greggs plan']})
```

I want to create a parent ID and based on the `phone` and `email` columns and create a note how the record was matched.

I'm trying to output a dataframe like this without much luck:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'parent.id':[1,2,1,3,4,4,5,1,],
                   'matched': ['none','none','phone','none','email','email','none','email'],
                   'id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                   'forename':['matt','mark','matthew','chris','rob','robert','john','mat'],
                   'surname': ['smith','smith','smith','jones','quiton','quiton','rogers','smith'],
                   'phone': ['77881','77882','77881','66777','12299','93923','77881','37882'],
                   'email': ['email1@email.com','email2@email.com','email3@email.com','email4@email.com','email5@email.com','email5@email.com','email7@email.com','email1@email.com'],
                   'group': ['greggs','kikland','greggs group','dmrc','curve','tools','baron','greggs plan']})
```

Can someone help?

Comment: what have you tried and what is that you're struggling with?

Comment: id 2 can also be matched with id 8 base on phone number, is that intended?

Comment: @SandervandenOord it was sorry, just fixed that.

Comment: @FlavioMoraes I've been trying to create the table using df.merge, by merging it on itself twice based on each column. I'm fairly new to python and haven't been able get it into the shape require.

Comment: do you want to merge the phone and the email? They are strings you can just sum them: df['ṕarent_id'] = df['phone']+df['email']

Comment: @FlavioMoraes I want to create the parent ID on the condition that either 'phone' or 'email' matches and assign a parent ID without duplicate connections so that id=5 and id=6 are not in the table twice in opposite order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [.groupby().transform()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to get to this.

My trick is to group by email and take the minimum id of the group. They all get assigned the minimum id of their group as a possible parent id

Then I do the same for grouping by phone.

Finally I look at the results of both separate groupings and determine the new parent id by taking the minimum value of found id's.

```
df['email_match'] = df.groupby('email')['id'].transform('min')
df['matched_by_email'] = df.groupby('email')['id'].transform('count') > 1

df['phone_match'] = df.groupby('phone')['id'].transform('min')
df['matched_by_phone'] = df.groupby('phone')['id'].transform('count') > 1

df['parent_id'] = df[['email_match', 'phone_match']].min(axis=1)
```

Some entries in your example can be matched by both phone and email.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you told me you can create a new df excluding the rows where there is a phone or email duplicated using the pandas method `duplicated()`

```
phone_dup = df['phone'].duplicated()
email_dup = df['email'].duplicated()

new_df = df[~phone_dup & ~email_dup]
```

you can create your new id based on this new df